# How can travelers ensure their safety when flying during the COVID-19 epidemic?

Tags: covid-19

In light of the current pandemic, how can travelers ensure that they're not infected while taking the plane? Would it be sufficient to wear a N95 mask with protective goggles or does one require a full-blown hazmat protection suit to ensure absolute safety?

I am aware that the best course of action is to avoid travel altogether, but let's presume that this is not an option.

Comment: I feel there's no such thing as absolute safety in this situation. If you're on a public flight, there's always going to be a risk of infection. On top of that the airlines are likely to limit what equipment you're allowed to use on a flight. Is the criteria of the question strictly limited to public flights or would plane charter be an option?

Comment: @zeocrash public flights only

Comment: Planes are considered the most secure, due the regular air exchange within the airplane. It is outside the plane (Airport, busses, trains and their stations) where an unexpected coughing of a single person can cause problems for all within a range of 1-2 meters.

Comment: I don't thing absolute safety from infection is possible on a public flight. AFAIK, PPE like hazmat suits and respirators are unlikely to be allowed on flights. A guy was recently thrown off a flight in the US for wearing a full respirator. There's obviously ways to mitigate the risk, but as long as you're cooped up with the general public there's no absolute guarantees of safety.

Comment: In an ideal world, for absolute safety, i'd recommend a Racal suit and a powered respirator with a HEPA filter. They can be used on planes as the US government Aeromedical Isolation Team uses them when flying casualties with highly contageous diseases. That said, i don't imagine any airline would let you board wearing one as it would likely panic the passengers. Also it makes eating, drinking and going to the bathroom impossible without removing the suit.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racal_suit

Comment: An expert was asked about that on the TV, sorry I don't recall the name, and he said that he was not going to wear a mask but would decline any food or beverage on the aircraft that the flight crew would touch, avoid the dirty tray tables and not touch his face or eyes during the flight. Maybe bring a small hand sanitizer (100ml or less).

Answer (score 3):

Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) advice for the public: [When and how to use masks](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/advice-for-public/when-and-how-to-use-masks)

- If you are healthy, you only need to wear a mask if you are taking care of a person with suspected 2019-nCoV infection.
- Wear a mask if you are coughing or sneezing.
- Masks are effective only when used in combination with frequent hand-cleaning with alcohol-based hand rub or soap and water.
- If you wear a mask, then you must know how to use it and dispose of it properly.

From : https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019

Protection measures for everyone
Stay aware of the latest information on the COVID-19 outbreak, available on the WHO website and through your national and local public health authority. Many countries around the world have seen cases of COVID-19 and several have seen outbreaks. Authorities in China and some other countries have succeeded in slowing or stopping their outbreaks. However, the situation is unpredictable so check regularly for the latest news.

You can reduce your chances of being infected or spreading COVID-19 by taking some simple precautions:

- Regularly and thoroughly clean your hands with an alcohol-based hand
  rub or wash them with soap and water. Why? Washing your hands with soap and water or using alcohol-based hand rub kills viruses that may be on your hands.
- Maintain at least 1 metre (3 feet) distance between yourself and anyone who is coughing or sneezing.Why? When someone coughs or sneezes they spray small liquid droplets from their nose or mouth which may contain virus. If you are too close, you can breathe in the droplets, including the COVID-19 virus if the person coughing has the disease.
- Avoid touching eyes, nose and mouth.
  Why? Hands touch many surfaces and can pick up viruses. Once contaminated, hands can transfer the virus to your eyes, nose or mouth. From there, the virus can enter your body and can make you sick.
- Make sure you, and the people around you, follow good respiratory hygiene. This means covering your mouth and nose with your bent elbow or tissue when you cough or sneeze. Then dispose of the used tissue immediately.Why? Droplets spread virus. By following good respiratory hygiene you protect the people around you from viruses such as cold, flu and COVID-19.
- Stay home if you feel unwell. If you have a fever, cough and difficulty breathing, seek medical attention and call in advance. Follow the directions of your local health authority.Why? National and local authorities will have the most up to date information on the situation in your area. Calling in advance will allow your health care provider to quickly direct you to the right health facility. This will also protect you and help prevent spread of viruses and other infections.
- Keep up to date on the latest COVID-19 hotspots (cities or local areas where COVID-19 is spreading widely). If possible, avoid traveling to places  – especially if you are an older person or have diabetes, heart or lung disease. Why? You have a higher chance of catching COVID-19 in one of these areas.